# Unable to convert ForwardedEvents.evtx to csv format

Tags: windows, powershell, msdn

I have encountered strange behavior.
I have created windows event forwarding subscription and `ForwardedEvent.evtx` file is capturing subscribed events. When trying to convert `ForwardedEvent.evtx` file to csv file I see `System.AccessViolation` exception. I used command

```
Get-WinEvent -Path C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs\ForwardedEvents.evtx |Export-Csv ForwardedEvents.csv
```

in powershell admin mode

I tried copying `ForwardedEvents.evtx` file to other location and convert still I see same issue.
I tried to convert other files `Application.evtx` and `Hardware.evtx` file in `C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs` that works fine and only this `ForwardedEvent.evtx` unable to convert.

[image]

Comment: Are you able to read the file via Event Viewer?

Comment: Yes, I am able to read the file via Event Viewer. When I double click on ForwardedEvent.evtx file opens in Event Viewer and able the see the captured events too. But unable to convert to CSV for further processing.

Comment: Maybe it has to be unmounted from event viewer.

Comment: Unmounted from Event viewer, still not able to convert. Also tried copying copying file to other location and then converting, still same issue. Only this file has issue other files like Application, security etc able to convert to csv

Comment: I continued further with my investigation and tried in different laptops. I observed laptop with Windows 10 Enter does not have any issue and able to convert file successfully. But laptop with Win 11 Enter does not allow and throws System.AccessViolationException.  Need to find way to get the access in Win 11 OS